# Zooming images on page load

Tags: javascript, html, image

I would like to get the effect of a zooming image when someone opens a new page. So each page should have it's own image that zooms in every time the page is opened. I have an example in this website: http://www.fashionclub70.be/ (Click the "light version").

If a user clicks on a menuitem the corresponding page is opened and the image zooms in. on this website it is done with Flash, but I would like to use only Javascript for this. I don't really have a working knowledge of Flash. Do you have some pointers for me so I can successfully implement this?

Thanks

Maarten

Comment: That is not zoom but some kind of revealing.

Comment: There are quite a few ways to go about implementing something like this.  Two notable ones would be with either CSS, which has less browser support, or jQuery. Do you feel confident working with JavaScript/jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the easiest solution would be to use something like this : http://sliderjs.org/. Basically, you would put an empty place holder and load your image to some invisible div element.
Then, kick off a transition effect with a callback bound to your image's onload event.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a canvas and put a picture on it. Evertything you would need for this can be found here:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/

Edit: If you want to use CSS3 you could use

```
#pix{width:200px;height:300px;transition: all 2s;}

#pic:hover{transform:scale(4) translate(100px,100px)}
```

This would make the div tagged with this id move to the right and become 4 times as large during a period of 2 seconds. 
The :hover part is just an event that would make the transition tick. Guess you want to use  :active instead.